# Java: Adding strings into a multi-dimensional char array

Tags: java, string, arraylist, multidimensional-array, char

I was messing around with 2D arrays and trying to build a program that places strings into a 2D char array and fills out the remaining spaces with random letters. I can do everything up to filling up the array with the random chars, but I can't figure out how to get the strings into the char array. This is how I'm thinking about tackling it, in pseudocode because I haven't been able to properly figure this out.

1. I saved the strings into an ArrayList called `words` (already coded this part).
2. I wanted to go through each of the elements in that ArrayList and compare the length of each one with the space available in the char array
3. Determine where it won't go out of bounds if added, and save those "coordinates" into another ArrayList.
4. Then, using those coordinates I would convert the words into chars one by one and replace the random chars that were already in the array with them.

This all makes sense to me in my head and written down (please let me now if it doesn't), but the problem is I have no idea how to actually implement the "determine where it won't go out of bounds" part. Specifically, I don't know how to actually determine which spaces in the array are too close to the "edge" for me to add the words without going out of bounds.

I'd really appreciate any help, and sorry for the wall of text. Thanks!

**Edit**: Here's the code I have so far. As I mentioned before I haven't added the part I wrote in pseudocode above because I don't know how.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BuildArray
{
    private char [][]arrayBoard;
    private int row, col;
    private String inWord;
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void build()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //takes in user input

        System.out.println("How many rows?");
        row = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many columns?");
        col = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        do{
            System.out.println("Add a word to array (quit to stop) >");
            inWord = input.nextLine();

            if(!inWord.equals("quit"))
            {
                words.add(inWord);
            }

        }while(!inWord.equals("quit"));

        fillArray(); 
    }

    public void fillArray()
    {
        arrayBoard = new char[row][col];

        for(int rows = 0; rows < board.length; rows++)
        {
            for(int cols = 0; cols < board[rows].length; cols++)
            {
                arrayBoard[rows][cols] = randomChar();
            }
        }

    }

    public char randomChar()
    {
        char alphabet[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
        'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
        'y', 'z'};

        return alphabet[(char)(alphabet.length * Math.random())];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what an input string should look like before and after it's been parsed? And what's the **board** variable?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your problem is to put each character from the string into that 2D char array.
Well, I suggest converting the input string to a 1D char array, then you can add each character from that 1D char array to the 2D char array.
Try adding these 2 methods to you code, I assumed that you need to add the string characters randomly to the array, if not, you can replace the part of generating random indices for the 2D array.

```
    private char[] stringToArray() {
    // added method to convert input string to char array
    return this.inWord.toCharArray();
}


    public void fillArrayWithString() {
    // added method to insert string randomly in the 2D char array
    int stringArrayLength = stringToArray().length;
    int iterator = 0;
    int cols;
    int rows;
    while (iterator < stringArrayLength) {
        rows = (int) (arrayBoard.length * Math.random());
        if (rows < arrayBoard.length) {
            cols = (int) (arrayBoard[rows].length * Math.random());
            if (cols < arrayBoard[rows].length) {
                arrayBoard[rows][cols] = stringToArray()[iterator++];
            }
        }
    }
}
```